# using revealing module pattern with Knockout and Asp.net MVC4

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I'm trying to use knockout with my asp.net mvc 4 app. and this is what my code looks like.

```
    <script>


var my = my || {}; //creating private namespace to avoid any conflicts other namespaces: my namespace

$(document).ready(function () {



    ////////////////view model testing////////////////////////////

    // Define Main ViewModel; javascript Object Literals
    ////it is a workaround for moduler JS pattern including revealing js pattren 
    ///it also uses KnockOut. end product ViewModel; 

    function teammemberModel() {
        this.Id = ko.observable();
        this.Title = ko.observable();
        this.Name = ko.observable();
        this.Email = ko.observable();
        this.Nationality = ko.observable();
        this.Sex = ko.observable();

    };


    my.viewModel = function () {

        var teamMembers = ko.observableArray([]),

            loadTeamMembers = function (projectId) {                
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "/Project/GetTeamMembers?projectId=" + projectId,

                    success: function (response) {

                        my.viewModel.teamMembers.removeAll();
                        $.each(response.results, function (x, team) {
                            my.viewModel.teamMembers.push(new teammemberModel()
                                .Id(team.Id)
                                .Title(team.Title)
                                .Name(team.UserName)
                                .Email(team.Email)
                                .Nationality(team.Nationality)
                                .Sex(team.Sex)

                            );



                        });
                    }                        
                });
            }
        return {
            teamMembers: teamMembers,
            loadTeamMembers: loadTeamMembers
        };
    } ();

    //Applies KO bindings        
    ko.applyBindings(my.viewModel);
    my.viewModel.loadTeamMembers(6);

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////       

    });    
    </script>
```

This is sample Modular JS implementation for my client side Knockout base viewmodel. My view looks like following.

```
    <table >    
    <thead>
    <tr>

        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Created By</th>
        <th>Created Date</th>
    </tr>
</thead>    
<tbody data-bind="foreach: teamMembers">

    <tr>                            
        <td data-bind="text: UserName"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: Email"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: Sex"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: Title"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: Nationality"></td>

    </tr>                        

      </tbody>
    </table>
```

I can see json data being pushed into the teamMembers ko.observableArray in my ajax call. This code should be working as per the tutorial that I'm trying to follow but i doesn't show my any data within my table. Can somebody guide me whats wrong with this code and why my table is not being rendered here. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your client side code looks fine might be something wrong with your server side code.  Check what you are returning from server especially is data returning in response variable.

I think response.result dont have any data that is why you are getting exception.  So please debug your client side code.

```
$.each(response.results, function (x, team) {}
```

Comment: I've already debugged my js and as I was saying data is there and being pushed in to the observableArray,

Comment: I also check the same code data was populated in table.  I use webapi for it and remove the .result because my result was in response varibale.  It would be good if you write your server side code or use jsfiddle.net to demonstrate